# Mongoose .find works until query criteria is entered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

If I add my "query" to workflow.find{} I don't get a response.

I'm thinking my naming for my sub documents isn't correct.

I need to be able to drill down past the Workflow and Components level.

I've tried removing the texto. part and even calling the name field directly but not sure what I'm missing.

```
router.get('/findcomponent', (req, res) =>{
        const workflow = require('../models/WorkFlowOnly.js')
        const id = req.params.id
        const query = {'texto.Workflow.Name' : 'Test WE'} //works


    workflow.find(query, function(err, data) { console.log(data)  /* ... */});//works

    })
```

Console Log with filtered results

```
{ _id: 5c8fbe0ed6dd2e0f6c5f7990,
  texto:
   { Workflow:
      { ID: 'Workflow-STARK-ahinson1-2019.03.03-20.14.43-VYHP',
        LocalCachePath: 'Z:\\MAITest\\Cache',
        SharedCachePath: null,
        Name: 'Test WE',
        Desc: 'I\'m testing this',
        Components: [Object] } },
  Components: [] }


Data
```

log from console when no query is defined:

```
[ { _id: 5c8fad698481aa2a881f9caa,
    texto: { Workflow: [Object] },
    Components: [] },
  { _id: 5c8fbe0ed6dd2e0f6c5f7990,
    texto: { Workflow: [Object] },
    Components: [] } ]
```

Update: That did work thank you very much, I'm running into a similar issue when i try digging past the Component level.
This is my new query code i'm trying, i've tried some other variations here's two.

```
const query = {'texto.Workflow.Components.Component.0.ID' : 'ImageReaderComponentGRQL'} 
const query = {'texto.Workflow.Components.Component.Component.0.ID' : 'ImageReaderComponentGRQL'} 
const query = {'texto.Workflow.Components.Component.0.ID' : 'ImageReaderComponentGRQL2'} //THIS WORKS -----UPDATED
```

Below is a copy/paste of the mongodb list view of a test record.

```
id:5c8fbe0ed6dd2e0f6c5f7990
texto:Object
Workflow:Object
ID:"Workflow-2019.03.03-20.14.43-VYHP"
LocalCachePath:"Z:\MAITest\Cache"
SharedCachePath:null
Name:"Test WE"
Desc:"I'm testing shit so fuck off"
Components:Object
Component:Array
0:Object
ID:"ReaderComponentGRQL2"
Type:"ReaderComponent"
Name:"ReaderU08"
Desc:null
Properties:Object
InputPorts:null
OutputPorts:Object
1:Object
2:Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mongo `query` is incorrect

```
const query = {'texto.Workflow.Name' : 'Test WF'} // here
workflow.find(query, function(err, data) { console.log(data)  /* ... */});

})
```

Comment: That worked, I'm running into a similar issue when i try digging past the Component level.

Comment: @JustinMiller Next time try to give full problem statement at once and more briefly explained. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using as below:

```
   router.get('/findcomponent', (req, res) =>{
        const workflow = require('../models/WorkFlowOnly.js')
        const id = req.params.id
        // const query = "['texto.Workflow.Name' : 'Test WF'}"
        const query = { 'texto.Workflow.$.Name' : 'Test WF' }

    workflow.find(query, function(err, data) { 
        console.log(data)  /* ... */
       });
    })
```

or optionally you can do it without using `const query` as below:

```
       workflow.find({'texto.Workflow.Name': "TEST WF"}, function(err, data) { 
            console.log(data)  /* ... */
           });
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, this is what i figure out
This query worked for my array sub documents

```
const query = {'texto.Workflow.Components.Component.0.ID' : 'ImageReaderComponent'}
```